# Can Amplitude Amplification amplify an unknown state?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, grovers-algorithm, amplitude-amplification

If you have for example the basis states $|000\rangle$ and $|xxx\rangle$. The value of the second basis state is unknown, but the amplitude of both states is given. Also the amplitude of the second state is really small. My question is whether it is possible to amplify the basis state $|xxx\rangle$

Comment: How is this question different from your previous one?

Comment: I didn´t get a good answer, so i reformulated my question.

Comment: Yes, thank you!